# Buttondownfcn gui axes

Tags: matlab, matplotlib

I have a Gui, that it has an axes...In the axes i can draw lines with plot.. but i want to select a line of the axes.. i have tried with buttondownfcn..but it doesn't work.. i have a button DELETE and its callback is:

```
hold all;
set(handles.axes6, 'HitTest', 'off');
set(handles.axes6,'ButtonDownFcn',('h = copyobj(gcbo,figure)'));
delete_object_axes = findobj(h, 'Type', 'line');
```

My code is:

```
% --- Executes on mouse press over axes background.
function axes6_ButtonDownFcn(~, ~, handles)
% hObject    handle to axes6 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
hold all;
set(handles.axes6, 'HitTest', 'off');
set(handles.axes6, 'ButtonDownFcn', {@Delete_Callback, handles}');


% --- Executes on mouse press over figure background, over a disabled or
% --- inactive control, or over an axes background.
function figure1_WindowButtonDownFcn(~, ~, handles)
% hObject    handle to figure1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
hold all;enter code here
global h;
set(handles.axes6, 'HitTest', 'off');
h = findobj(handles.axes6, 'Type', 'line');
set(h, 'ButtonDownFcn', {@Delete_Callback});
```

Help me..how can i select and delete a line??? or move??? there is some manner to do it????
It is very important for me..please!! help me!:)

Comment: Did I understand correctly - you want to be able to select a line from an axes when clicking on it, and having it deleted when you click on a "delete" button?

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example code that should help you achieve what you want, based on [this discussion in MATLABcentral](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/63864-how-to-select-point-or-lines-on-the-graph). What it does is checl if you clicked on a line, if you did, it modifies it, and if you click it again it is deleted. You can paste it in a file and run.

```
function init()
    close all; clear variables; clc;
    ax1=ezplot('sin(x)');
    set(ax1,'ButtonDownFcn',@mouseClick);
end

function mouseClick(source, event)
    if strcmp(get(source,'Type'),'line')
        if get(source,'linewidth')==2
            delete(source);
            return
        end
        %// Store the handle "source" someplace

        %// Demonstration modification:
        set(source,'linewidth',2);
    end
end
```

**Edit**: here's a bit more complicated example, showing how to save variables to the `handles` structure (a.k.a. `guidata`):

```
function init()
    close all; clear variables; clc;
    hLine(1) = ezplot('sin(x)'); hold all; hLine(2) = ezplot('cos(x)');
    set(hLine(:),'ButtonDownFcn',@mouseClick);
    grid on
end

function mouseClick(hObject, eventdata)

 handles = guidata(gcf); %#1

 try
     if handles.delete_object_axes==hObject;
         delete(hObject);
         handles = rmfield(handles,'delete_object_axes');
     else
         set(handles.delete_object_axes,'linewidth',1);
         set(hObject,'linewidth',2);
         handles.delete_object_axes = hObject;
     end     
 catch
     if strcmp(get(hObject,'Type'),'line')
        handles.delete_object_axes = hObject;
        set(hObject,'linewidth',2);
        guidata(gca, handles);
     else
        set(handles.delete_object_axes,'linewidth',1);
     end
     return;
 end

 guidata(gca, handles);

end
```